# Update multiple records in one ActiveRecord transaction in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, transactions

How can I update/save multiple instances of a model in one shot, using a transaction block in Rails?

I would like to update values for hundreds of records; the values are different for each record. This is *not* a mass-update situation for one attribute. Model.update_all(attr: value) is not appropriate here.

```
MyModel.transaction do
    things_to_update.each do |thing|
        thing.score = rand(100) + rand(100)
        thing.save
    end
end
```

`save` seems to issue it's own transaction, rather than batching the updates into the surrounding transaction. I want all the updates to go in one big transaction.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: may be activerecord-import [gem](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki) would work for you..

Answer (score 3):

Say you knew that you wanted to set the things with ids 1, 2, and 3 to have scores, 2, 8, and 64 (as opposed to just random numbers), you could:

```
UPDATE 
  things AS t
SET
  score = c.score
FROM 
  (values
    (1, 2),
    (2, 30),
    (4, 50)
  ) as c(id, score) 
 where c.id = t.id;
```

So with Rails, you'd use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection#execute` to execute a block similar to the above, but with the correct value string interpolated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but possibly you are confusing *multiple transactions* with *multiple queries*.

The code you've posted will create a single transaction (e.g. if an exception occurred then all of the updates would be rolled back), but each `save` would result in a separate update query.

If it's possible to perform the update using SQL rather than Ruby code then that would probably be the best way to go.

Comment: I have to run updates on 1000 or so records at a time, so I don't want to run 1000 separate update queries, as it's much slower. Can you execute them all in one shot?

Comment: If the update really is to set `score` to the sum of 2 random numbers (and you've not just used that as an example to simplify the question) then you can use `update_all` but set the value using the postgres `random` function rather than using fixed values.

Answer (score -2):

I think that you need just change method "save" to "save!".
If any of the updates fail, the method save! generates an exception. When an exception occurs within a transaction block, the transaction reverses the entire operation (rollback)

```
MyModel.transaction do
    things_to_update.each do |thing|
    thing.score = rand(100) + rand(100)
    thing.save!
end
```

Comment: This will generate multiple SQL requests.