# Saving multiple updates and creates as one transaction - ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my current application I perform an update PUTS which updates certain attributes in multiple rows a table and also creates a new record in the same table. My code snippet of the controller looks like this:

```
  def update
    params[:p_types].values.each do |p_type_params|
        if p_type_params[:player_id]
            PlayerType.find(p_type_params[:player_id]).update_attributes p_type_params
        else
            @new_player_type = PlayerType.new(p_type_params)
            @new_player_type.save
        end 
    end
    redirect_to action: "index"
  end
```

Now this works fine if the process goes smoothly, it updates,creates and redirects back to the index picking up the values from the updated table. However, I dont want partial updates or row creation. If it fails for updates or creates due to some parameter constraints, then nothing happens to the table and redirects to the index as it was earlier. I believe the solution is to have everything grouped as one transaction, check for parameter sanity and then update the table. I am not able to find a concrete example for update or create, I tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967702/update-multiple-records-in-one-activerecord-transaction-in-rails) but wasnt very clear. Any help towards the solution would be really helpful !

Answer (score 1):

Although, its a bit difficult to understand what exactly your requirement is but as far I understand this is what you want,

In Rails 3 - `PlayerType.find_or_initialize_by(id: p_type_params[:player_id])`

And in rails 4 - `PlayerType.where(id:  p_type_params[:player_id]).first_or_initialize`

The above code will either find or initialise a new record in the table,

Note: You can also use `find_or_create_by` but this creates the object rather than initialising it. Hope that helps

Comment: I dont get it exactly, my concern is to make the updates and the create that is happening to be atomic. In the update, i supply with an id so that the corresponding column in the parameter is updated and in the create i dont supply because id is auto generated. And when I create I need some more control on creation so I need to do it as a if,else.

Comment: `@player_type = PlayerType.find_or_initialize_by(id: 'someid or nil')`, this statement will always return `@player_type`, after which you can also use the object to updates the attributes. If the id that your passing is nil then it will create a new object and which you can save after assigning any other values.

Comment: Okay, I kind of understand, I may have missed an information trying to simplify my problem. While I create a player, I create this way `squad.player_type.new(p_type_params)`, so that squad_id is initilized as its a foriegn key to PlayerType. Can I still get it to work the way you are suggesting?

Comment: Yes you can. You may as well think of having `find_or_initialize_by` on multiple columns which is what you want.

Comment: Any reason you would know why it would say `undefined method `find_or_initialize_by'`

Comment: Depends. which rails version ? Are you invoking this on on a class ? or object ? or tell me how exactly your code looks like only then its possible for people to point out where your going wrong

Comment: PlayerType is a model class player_type.rb, Let me see if i can elaborate the question. Also I am using rails 3

Comment: I figured the issue, but it says cant mass assign id, which should not be the case right because ideally I only want it to find by id or initialize id and not assign it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65253/discussion-between-pamio-solanky-and-tanvi).